# Is it possible to create own class in Django views to avoid code duplicates?

Tags: python, django

I have 3 subpages to redirect to and each of them must contain the same piece of code:

```
new_user = User.objects.get(username=user)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=new_user)
    adverts = Advert.objects.filter(user=new_user)
    editable = False
    if request.user.username == user:
        editable = True
    context = {
        "objects":adverts,
        "user_profile":user_profile,
        "no_data":"No comments",
        "editable":editable,
        "user":user
    }
```

and only "objects" in context change. 3 almost the same methods don;t look good. Is there a way to inherit that code from one class or maybe create own tag to do it ? I'm kinda new in django and I do not know what are the good habits here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, why not?

Just abstract the code out like so:

```
class View1(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        [...]
        context = makeContext(request, user, Adverts)   # or whoever `user` is
        return render(request, 'template.html', context)

def makeContext(request, user, model):
    new_user = User.objects.get(username=user)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=new_user)
    objects = model.objects.filter(user=new_user)
    editable = False
    if request.user.username == user:
        editable = True
    context = {
        "objects": objects,
        "user_profile": user_profile,
        "no_data": "No comments",
        "editable": editable,
        "user": user
    }
    return context
```

Comment: Ok so I need to create base method like makeContext and then 3 views class, right  ?

Comment: @deri yes exactly

Comment: cool :) Could you please just explain me how can I modfiy context in each class  ?

Comment: @deri you can do this by adding the variable you want into ‘makeContext’ signature, and then feeding it through the ‘makeContext()’ function parameters. You can then use them inside of the shared function.

Comment: what about if I want to edit context's items ? Exactly the first item of dictionary - objects. Would you mind to edit the code so I can see it ? Sorry for bothering you :)

Comment: @deri you mean you want to filter a model other than Advert?

Comment: Exactly. AS mentioned each of those methods differ only with one item in context. Here objects represent adverts. Second objects represent sth else etc. I simply want to inherit the base and just filter different model (adverts variable)

Comment: @deri I updated the answer to show how this can be done